# Command line tools only sdkmanager: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: javascript, java, windows, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to execute `sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"` but i always have the same problem  (Windows 10, JDK is in `C:\jdk`)

Java version:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

sdkmanager command:

```
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"
    Unrecognized option: -
    Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
    Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

sdkmanager file is (i did not modify it):

```
@if "%DEBUG%" == "" @echo off
@rem ##########################################################################
@rem
@rem  sdkmanager startup script for Windows
@rem
@rem ##########################################################################

@rem Set local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" setlocal

set DIRNAME=%~dp0
if "%DIRNAME%" == "" set DIRNAME=.
set APP_BASE_NAME=%~n0
set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%..

@rem Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and SDKMANAGER_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=%~dp0\..

@rem Find java.exe
if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome

set JAVA_EXE=java.exe
%JAVA_EXE% -version >NUL 2>&1
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:findJavaFromJavaHome
set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:"=%
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

if exist "%JAVA_EXE%" goto init

echo.
echo ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: %JAVA_HOME%
echo.
echo Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
echo location of your Java installation.

goto fail

:init
@rem Get command-line arguments, handling Windows variants

if not "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" goto win9xME_args

:win9xME_args
@rem Slurp the command line arguments.
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
set _SKIP=2

:win9xME_args_slurp
if "x%~1" == "x" goto execute

set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*

:execute
@rem Setup the command line

set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\/sdkmanager-classpath.jar

@rem Execute sdkmanager
"%JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%  -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end
@rem End local scope for the variables with windows NT shell
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mainEnd

:fail
rem Set variable SDKMANAGER_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of
rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!
if  not "" == "%SDKMANAGER_EXIT_CONSOLE%" exit 1
exit /b 1

:mainEnd
if "%OS%"=="Windows_NT" endlocal

:omega
```

I set the JAVA_HOME variable to match the JDK but it is not working:

[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that the solution was to move everything under `C:\cmdline-tools\tools\bin`